# Document Properties Demotion from ListItem field is not working

Tags: development, content-type, document-template, document-info-panel

I have a content type in a library configured with a word document as a template, it is the default content type.
When creating via the UI from New item entering information into the DIP sets values in the document via Quick Part Document Properties. 
These entries are reflected on the underlying SharePoint list item and in the body of the document.

If I re-open the document the changes in the DIP do not get reflected in the Document body.

If I create a document via code using the template file, set the list item field the list item properties are not reflected in the document at all. They can be found when I inspect the XML but they never get demoted into the body of the document.

```
Hashtable properties = new Hashtable
                            {
                                {"ApplicationNumber", "CP1234567"},
                                {"DealerName", "Jim Bob Harry"},
                                {"DealerFax", "094025566"},
                                {"CustFirstName", "Gustav"},
                                {"CustLastName", "Gustavisson"},
                                {"FPFCompany", "RFS"}
                            };
SPFolder rootFolder = list.RootFolder;
SPFile spFile = rootFolder.Files.Add(string.Format("{0}.docx", Guid.NewGuid()), Resources.DeclinedFaxTemplate, properties);
```

Any body got any pointers as to how we can try and ensure that the document and the list item properties are kept in sync?

Answer (score 3):

I've just made a small test of difference ways to create a word document in the file system and then use it to programatically create documents in a document library with properties.

**Create not using SharePoint**
Create document/template from scrach in Word. Add Custom properties. Add Quick Part using Field|DocProperty|Property. Save to file system

Result:
Properties showing in Quick Part: Value from source
Properties showing in DIP/File|Info: Value from program/SP

**Create using contenttype in SharePoint save to file system**
Go to Document library with properties. Click New Document(or your contenttype) button in Ribbon. Add Quick Part using Document Property|Property. Save to file system<

Result:
Properties showing in Quick Part: Value from program/SP
Properties showing in DIP/File|Info: Value from program/SP

**Create using contenttype in SharePoint extract to file system**
Go to Document library with properties. Click New Document(or your contenttype) button in Ribbon. Add Quick Part using Document Property|Property. Save to Document library. Use program to extract to file system

Result:
Properties showing in Quick Part: Value from program/SP
Properties showing in DIP/File|Info: Value from program/SP

**Conclusion**
So it seems that the important part is to use SharePoint to create the document based on your contenttype, so that it gets the properties in the right way.

I also ran a test creating the documents in SP programatically, extracting them from SP into file system programatically and then opening them in word. And the result was the exact same as opening directly from SP. So if SP is allowed to create the properties in the first place it seems it's capable of maintaining it without help from the client program.

Test performed on SP2010 Enterprise. Documents create using Word 2010 as .docx files.

This is the code used to extract the document in the last test:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace ExtractDocument
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var site =new SPSite("http://sp2010"))
            using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                var doclib = web.GetList("MyDocLib") as SPDocumentLibrary;
                foreach (SPFile source in doclib.RootFolder.Files)
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format("C:\\testdocs2\\{0}", source.Name), source.OpenBinary());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the code used to create documents based on the content from the file system:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace GenerateDocuments
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var site = new SPSite("http://sp2010"))
            using (var web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                var doclib = web.GetList("MyDocLib") as SPDocumentLibrary;
                foreach (var sourceName in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\testdocs"))
                {
                    var source = new FileInfo(sourceName);
                    Console.WriteLine(source.Name);
                    doclib.RootFolder.Files.Add(source.Name, File.ReadAllBytes(sourceName), new Hashtable { { "Property1", "From Create" }, { "Property2", "From Create" } });
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please post a sample of the code used to create the document programatically?

Comment: My create code was very based on your sample, but I've added both my programs to my answer

Answer (score 1):

I believe Property promotion and demotion will only occur when a document is uploaded or downloaded via the SP web UI or via WebDav (folder open in Windows Explorer for example).

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem, there are 2 things 2 keep in mind:

Fields in a word file use the SourceID property of a field, if that field is created using XML in a feature and the source id is not set in the XML, sharepoint will regenerate it. So a template created on Farm A (DEV) will not work on System B (PRD), seeing as the SourceID will be different (usually a GUID, i keep it the same as the actual field ID)

SharePoint does not always actually update the word file when programmatically changing a field on the listitem / adding an item. You can to do this yourself using Word Automation Services.

Answer (score 0):

Here is 'my tuppence worth':

From my experience (in certain scenarios) [SPFileCollection.Add Method (String, Byte(), Hashtable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472956.aspx) (or any other [SPFileCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfilecollection.add.aspx) overload with Hashtable) can  fail to update document properties.

I had similar issue while adding files to library using similar code (like in question above). After some time I ended with this:

```
var file = destinationFolder.Files.Add(strDestUrl, binFile, true); 
file.Item["MyField1"] = MyFieldValue1;
file.Item["MyField2"] = MyFieldValue2;
...
file.Item.SystemUpdate(false);
```

This code first creates document and then it changes document properties. `SystemUpdate` is used to avoid multiple versions.

I really don't recall exact scenario when `SPFileCollection.Add+Hashtable` failed me (it was more then a year ago) but since then I am using above approach in all of my projects.